# Save GXT Tree to XML file in Java

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

How to save GXT Tree content (com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.tree.Tree) to a XML file in Java?

Comment: Please provide your existing code

Answer (score 0):

**Quid Pro Quo.** A less detailed answer would be as follows

You would be anyway using a List of Lists via Store or DataProviders. Send them to server by Serializing them over RPC or JSON via RequestBuilder. Use a XML library to convert them to XML file on the run and in the on success call of rpc/request builder give a url to download the xml file if required.

**Note** - This can be done any number of ways depending on the details of your requirement and your expertise!!!!